# Passing string as a property to object

Tags: javascript, json

```
function createObject(arg1, arg2){ 
       var object = {};
           object.arg1 = arg2;
}
```

I am calling my function like this.

```
   createObject('name', objectproperties);
```

The problem i am facing is when the request object is formed. Its something like this

```
{"arg1":{"Properties":"Value"}}
```

I want my object to be formed like this. Its a generic class, which i am creating for many requests to be formed.

```
{"name":{"Properties":"Value"}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use square bracket notation:

```
object[arg1] = arg2;
```

**Reference:** http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html#vId

Answer (score 1):

```
object[arg1] = arg2;
```

That should work.